# How to create dynamic tabs with Tabset component using a child component?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

Recently I started to develop with Angular and ng-bootstrap. I'm working on a form with the help of Reactive Forms which contains some FormControls and a nested FormArray. For each element in the FormArray, I want to display a child component that belongs to a tab of a Tabset component of ng-bootstrap but the child component doesn't render.

The form is divided into two components: MainForm and SubForm. MainForm contains some FormControls, one FormArray, an instance of Tabset and instance of SubForm for each element in FormArray. SubForm is a tab of Tabset that contains a nested form some input fields.

When I render MainForm an API call is fired and returns some data to fill the form. FormControls and FormArray of MainForm are filled but SubForm doesn't render.

I reproduced the issue with the minimal configuration in a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nny3qb) using Stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `NgbTabSet` component can't initialize `NgbTab` directives which are created inside `SubForm` because `NgbTabSet` requires `NgbTab` to be [ContentChildren](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/b193bc690600bed2983619c2c8d12c7e624c59d2/src/tabset/tabset.ts#L127)

It means you have to keep `ngb-tab` elements inside `ngb-tabset` as projected content:

**main-form.component.html**

```
<ngb-tabset type="pills" [destroyOnHide]="true">
  <ngb-tab *ngFor="let hobbie of hobbies.controls; let i=index" [attr.id]="index">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
      <span>Hobbie {{ i + 1 }}</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <app-sub-form [subForm]="hobbie"></app-sub-form>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

I also think that it forces you to keep your SubForm component not to be dependent on NgbTabSet so you can use this form somewhere else.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qk51gk?file=src/app/sub-form/sub-form.component.html)**